# Excel formula that conditionally sums up durations

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet with two columns.

First column has a timestamp with date and time and the second contains the status of a machinery that is reported with 1 when it was on and 0 when it was off.

I need an Excel formula that reports the total amount of time that the machinery was on between two timestamps.

The Excel has the following form:

```
22/12/2022 11:13 1
22/12/2022 11:58 0
23/12/2022 13:16 1
23/12/2022 13:58 1
24/12/2022 23:03 1
24/12/2022 23:42 0
```

For example the data above the total time duration would be 11:10:00

Comment: What about a pivot table? Or subtotals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks easy:

[image]

Fill down the formula from C2 to C6.

Alternatively you can use the next formula in any single cell:

```
=REDUCE(0,B1:B5,LAMBDA(a,b,a+(OFFSET(b,1,-1)-OFFSET(b,0,-1))*b))
```

Answer (score 3):

Or just

```
=SUM((A2:A6-A1:A5)*B1:B5)
```

Or  for a more general one in Excel 365:

```
=LET(a,TOCOL(A:A,1),b,TOCOL(B:B,1),SUM((DROP(a,1)-DROP(a,-1))*DROP(b,-1)))
```

[image]

Comment: I would call this formula '=SUM((A2:A6-A1:A5)*B1:B5)' the most elegant solution.